# Is it possble to replicate MySQL server on Azure virtual machines

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I have two Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machines on Azure. I need to replicate the database on each of the windows servers. I have followed [this link](http://udhyantimilsina.com/2012/10/25/master-to-master-replication-of-mysql-server-in-windows-server-2008/) but I am not getting the connection between the two MySQL servers. It is showing as connecting to master. Is there any other way to replicate MySQL databases on two different windows servers?

Comment: are both servers on same network? can you telnet the mysql port bothways?..

Comment: I'd imagine it's a firewall or security group issue. Ensure that the MySQL port is open between the hosts. Default is 3306.

Comment: i can connect to each of the mysql servers vms from my local machine machine mysql workbench

Answer (score 2):

For purposes of this discussion, there is only one way to replicate from one MySQL server to another, and the post that you linked to does seem to describe it correctly.

In this setup, the slave server needs to have the ability to establish a tcp connection to the master on port 3306. (The master never initiates this connection, so the connection only needs to be established from slave, to master.)

You can verify this on the slave at a command prompt:

```
C:\>mysql --host=ip.addr.of.master --port=3306 --user=username --password=password
```

The ip.addr.of.master should be the private IP of the master, and should be the same one you used in the `CHANGE MASTER TO` statement you executed on the slave.  You should also be able to use the username and password from the same statement to connect.

If this doesn't work, either, then the problem is probably **not** that you didn't follow the setup correctly, but is simply that the slave server's machine cannot reach the master machine over the network.

The steps to remedy this are going to be determined by the Azure setup, such as whether the two servers are in the same cloud service and virtual network, and whether there's a firewall on the master server that needs to be configured to allow access from the slave.

The command, above, should produce a numeric error code that you can translate into a descriptive error by using `perror nnnnn` command or by finding the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx).  I would expect, based on the description, that you will see 10060, connection timed out, which would be the strongest confirmation that what you have is a networking issue.